# How to create transparent pixels in a gif for BufferedImage, then save to a GIF file?

Tags: java, image, transparency, gif, opacity

I have code that creates a simple 5x5 array of [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html), and then uses that to create a [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). The edges of the array are an opaque color (`alpha = 255`) called `o`, while the center is a transparent color (`alpha = 0`) called `t`.

Finally, I write the image out to file using [`javax.imageio.ImageIO.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File)).

Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class Irrelevant
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
   
      final Color o = new Color(255, 0, 0, 255); //opaque red
      final Color t = new Color(0, 255, 0, 0);   //transparent green -- clear
   
      final Color[][] pixels = //red edges with (ideally) a clear center
         {
            {o, t, t, t, o},
            {o, t, t, t, o},
            {o, t, t, t, o},
            {o, t, t, t, o},
            {o, t, t, t, o}
         };
   
      BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(pixels.length, pixels[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   
      for (int y = 0; y < pixels.length; y++)
      {
         for (int x = 0; x < pixels[y].length; x++)
         {
            image.setRGB(x, y, pixels[y][x].getRGB());
         }
      }
   
      ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File("abctest.gif"));
      ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("abctest.png"));
   
   }

}
```

However, here is the resulting gif. I am showing it with a purple background to show that the image is ***NOT*** transparent in the center, like expected. It is actually black.

Don't mind the fuzziness, that's IrfanView being annoying.

[image]

And here is another one in Microsoft Paint. Same gif.

[image]

Why are they not clear in the center? And I know I set the `alpha` correctly because remember, I also saved it as a png as well as a gif. When I save it as a png, it works as expected. Here are screenshots for the png.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

EDIT - Here is an example image that I did not make.

[image]

In IrfanView, it looks like this.

[image]

In this gif, the purple shows up correctly, which is what threw me off.

But thanks to the help of @camickr, I am starting to think that it is actually something that only happens on IrfanView because all other image viewers I looked at it through worked. That includes, Photos, Snipping Tool, LibreOffice Draw, and Firefox. All showed a white (or background specific color) when rendering, implying that it is actually transparent.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: When I use Paint I get the same result as you. I tried to use the Color picker for both colors. However, the alpha value is not displayed, so I don't know what Paint is reading. I did try creating a simple GUI using a JLabel and the StretchIcon (from my blog) to display each image. Both showed as transparent in the frame.

Comment: Also, noticed that in Paint the "transparent" color for the png the color is (255, 255, 255) but for the gif it is (0, 0, 0). Don't know what it means, just an observation.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wow, could you describe your setup? I am Windows 11. Are you using something else? Do you think that this may be a bug with Java Swing?

Comment: @camickr Thanks for checking. Glad to hear that you are able to recreate this. I don't understand it either. As a side question, could you tell me what your set up is? Are you Windows 11? Linux? Based on MadProgrammer's response, it sounds like this might be set up specific.

Comment: @camickr As a side note, you can get the alpha value by calling the Color::getAlpha \method.

Comment: @camickr Using 0, 0, 0, 0 for the transparent didn't change anything, the color still came out Black

Comment: I"m Windows 11. MadProgrammer is Mac.

Comment: @camickr Interesting! Do you think this is worth submitting a bug report for?

Comment: Though, I should probably bounty the question first. If the bounty doesn't give an answer, then I will do it.

Comment: Playing more with paint and I found that it has a "background transparency" tool. When I used the tool the area I painted over also became black. I then retested the image in my GUi and it indeed did show as transparent. So the black you see in Paint appears to be the way it displays a transparent section since the background by default is white. Look in the "Image" section of paint and click on the drop down arrow of the rectangle in the left area of the image section.

Comment: I also tried using the "Open With" function of FileExplorer and opened the gif image in the "Snipping Tool" and I see a white background in the center of the image which matches the background of the image tool. So I don't think the is an issue with the image. Note, it would have been nice to work with a larger image in the Paint program to test the "background transparency" tool.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for taking the time to test this out! I guess for me, the thing that led me to believe it was not working was because of IrfanView. I have uploaded another image that is public gif from online (hope I don't get in trouble for using it). When I open it up in IrfanView, it shows purple as the background as expected. I do not get that for my image. I followed your cue, and started checking other image viewers, and all others worked out like you said, so I think you are actually correct. I tried snipping tool, Paint, Photos, Firefox, and LibreOffice Draw. All worked.

Comment: @camickr If you throw your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. If not, I can do it.

Comment: @davidalayachew Java 17.0.3.1 on MacOS Ventura 13.5.2

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ty vm! Yeah, looks like it is not a bug at all. I am signing up on the IrfanView message boards to see if it is a bug on their side.